# Command Line Script for Microsoft Expression Encoder Licensing

Tags: azure, batch-file, cmd, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-4

does anybody know how to activate Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 using Command Line Script. if yes, can you please guide me on how to do this.

Currently this is what i only have and it's not yet working because it still requires me to manually accept eula for installation.

```
 REM : Install Expression Encoder
 "%~dp0Encoder_en.exe" -q PROOFOFPURCHASE=[XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX] FORCEPRODUCTKEY=1 ACTIVATIONOPTIN=1

 REM : Exit Gracefully
 exit /b 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Can somebody please explain why would you put -1 on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/using-expression-encoder-4-in-a-windows-azure-worker-role/). They install encoder using [WebPICommandLine](http://blogs.iis.net/satishl/archive/2011/01/26/webpi-command-line.aspx), which has /accepteula parameter.

Comment: Hi, I had also tried to use this approach but it doesn't give you a way to validate you're product with the use of command prompt.